# Downloading a DOCX file from a DB using Classic ASP & VBScript

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I'm trying to maintain an old ASP page that retrieves a file from a DB and downloads it to the end user. This page works fine with older files but now "corrupts" files with a Docx file type.

I assume it was "corrupting" the older files too but Word was able to handle the minor differences whereas with the DocX format things are pickier.

The following is the code that does the download.

```
    Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    ' opening connection
    rs.Open "SELECT FileName, FileData, ContentType FROM Docs WHERE GetDocID='" & GetDoc & "'" , conn, 2, 4

    If Not rs.EOF Then
        Response.Clear()
        Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="& rs("FileName")
        Response.ContentType = rs("ContentType")
        Response.BinaryWrite rs("FileData")
        Response.Flush()
        'Response.Close()
        Response.End()

    End If

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
```

Any ideas what might be missing or causing the problem?

I have noticed that the pre-upload file is one byte bigger then the post-upload file.

Here is the upload code:

```
    Dim rs
    Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")             
    rs.Open "Docs", conn, 2, 2              
    rs.AddNew
    rs("FileName") = fileName
    rs("FileSize") = fileSize
    rs("FileData").AppendChunk = fileData
    rs("ContentType") = contentType
    rs("DocTitle") = DocTitle
    rs("ProjectID") = ProjectID                 
    rs.Update
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
```

Comment: Do you store the file size in your database? I've been burned by this and the problem was that sql is returning extra bytes. I don't recall the reason. I was able to fix it by pulling the data out in chunks and dropping everything after the file size.

Comment: Nope there is no file size stored. I will pursue that line.  Thanks

Comment: If it's failing to validate (can confirm this by running something like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler) because the Content-Length is wrong try adding this header `Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", LenB(rs("FileData")))`.

Comment: When you say it's *"corrupting"* what do you mean? Word reports an error, the file just doesn't load or the file loads but is gibberish to name just a few examples.

Comment: Sorry,  Word reports the file as being corrupt. But it recovers just fine. And if I change the extension to zip and compare the before and after contents everything is identical. I also did a checksum on the before and after but they show different...

Comment: You need to consider that while the old DOC "COULD" be transferred and handled as an ASCII format, the DOCX MUST be handled as binary or you will corrupt the file. SO must be opened in binary mode, read in binary mode and written in binary mode for it to remain valid.

Comment: Can you edit your question and show the upload code?

Answer (score 0):

Try writing explicitly in binary with the use of the ChrB(charcode) function.
(The ChrB function turns a character into a byte)

```
sFileData = rs("FileName")
For i=1 To Len(sFileData)
  Response.BinaryWrite ChrB(Mid(sFileData,i,1))
Next
```